# How to display a windows directory structure using MVC 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, directory, .net-4.5

I am working on a new project and have found no answers toward my problem other then a possible Jquery Tree plugin. I simply want to display to the user a "windows explorer" type view for navigating through a directory on a network. They can expand the folders under the root and open files just as if they were opening it normally without a browser. It's basically windows explorer in an mvc view. It seems like a common thing to do but google failed to help :( If anyone has a webkit, plugin, tutorial, or just suggestions please list them as i'm on drawing a blank for a simple solution. To do this dynamically is doable but requires a lot more work then i'd expect for such a common task.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to run into many browser security limitations here, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I basically just want to take what the windows explorer does in windows, and replicate it in an mvc View for users to navigate through a root directory. I'v found some jquery plugins but either they are old versions and outdated or cost a ton to use.

Comment: Yeah, that's because its a difficult problem to solve.  Are you looking to upload a file?  If so, you can just use an upload control.

Comment: Maess is correct in it is not a simple problem to solve.  Your best bet is to get your hands dirty and start playing around with some streams and try to build a basic visual representation of the files in a folder.  Take a look to get started here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx.  If you struggle with this come back and show some of the work you've tried and we can help further.

Comment: Fortunately i was able to find a built in plugin for KendoUI which i have a license for. I am going to try and take advantage of that and see how it turns out! Otherwise it's back to the drawing board and you'll be hearing from me! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem!!!! Recursion is beast! I found a lot of different ways to do it but this one worked out great. I converted the console.writelines to populate my MVC models but other then that i didn't change it. Highly recommend this tutorial!

[enter link description here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FolderRecursion.aspx)